# How to implement Socket server that accept more message

Tags: c#, android, sockets

I want to send at real time some data from Android application to server.

So I'm building a simple socket Server in c# like this:

```
class Program
    {
        private Socket listener;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.socketServer();
        }

        public void socketServer()
        {
            int MAXBUFFER = 1024;
            Console.WriteLine("SOCKET STARTED");
            listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            listener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8080));
            listener.Listen(10);
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("WAITING CONNECTION");
                Socket socket = listener.Accept();
                string receivedMessage = string.Empty;
                while (true)
                {
                    byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[MAXBUFFER];
                    int numBytes = socket.Receive(receivedBytes);
                    receivedMessage += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedBytes, 0, numBytes);
                    if (receivedMessage.IndexOf("\n") > -1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: {0}", receivedMessage);
                        //break;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: {0}", receivedMessage);
                string replyMessage = "MESSAGE RECEIVED";
                byte[] replyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(replyMessage);

            }
        }

        public void shutdownServer()
        {
            listener.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            listener.Close();
        }
    }
```

And I'm building this class to send data from Android application:

```
public class TcpClient {

    public static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.110.50"; // computer IP address
    public static final int SERVER_PORT = 8080;

    private String mServerMessage;
    private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
    private boolean mRun = false;
    private PrintWriter mBufferOut;
    private BufferedReader mBufferIn;
    private Socket socket;

    /**
     * Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
     */
    public TcpClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
        mMessageListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Sends the message entered by client to the server
     *
     * @param message text entered by client
     */
    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        socket.isConnected();
        if (mBufferOut != null /*&& !mBufferOut.checkError()*/) {
            mBufferOut.println(message);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Close the connection and release the members
     */
    public void stopClient() {
        Log.i("Debug", "stopClient");

        // send mesage that we are closing the connection
        //sendMessage(Constants.CLOSED_CONNECTION + "Kazy");

        mRun = false;

        if (mBufferOut != null) {
            mBufferOut.flush();
            mBufferOut.close();
        }

        mMessageListener = null;
        mBufferIn = null;
        mBufferOut = null;
        mServerMessage = null;
    }

    public void run() {

        mRun = true;

        try {
            //here you must put your computer's IP address.
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
        //create a socket to make the connection with the server
            socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);
            //socket.connect(socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            socket.isConnected();
            try {
                Log.i("Debug", "inside try catch");

                mBufferOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                        true);

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

            } finally {

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

        }

    }

     public interface OnMessageReceived {
        public void messageReceived(String message);
    }
}
```

And in the MainActivity I use this code:

```
tcpClient = new TcpClient(new TcpClient.OnMessageReceived() {
                        @Override
                        //here the messageReceived method is implemented
                        public void messageReceived(String message) {

                            //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                            //publishProgress(message);

                        }
                    });
                    tcpClient.run();
```

After connect to server i user this code to send message:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    tcpClient.sendMessage("test " + i);
}
```

The problem is that only the first message arrive to the server. I think that the problem is on the socket server that lost the connection with the client.

Comment: Have you tried attaching a breakpoint and debugging?

Comment: Yes I have attaching the dubugging on my Android app, and the connection it is ok, instead of in the server after write at console the first message, write WAITING CONNECTION

for this I think that the problem is on the socjet server that lose the connection to the client

Comment: What about the server side, where you stated you think there is a problem?

Comment: You are nowhere printing received messages on server side. So how would you know? Further the server checks for \n but the client is not sending a line end.

Comment: It is quite possible that the server receives all messages with one read. That is how tcp works. Dont think it will reveive ten times because the client sends ten times. All gets in one buffer.

Comment: Use Asynchronous Server which handles multiple connections.  The code uses sockets but you can replace with any class that inherits socket like TcpListener  See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples